# Reduce range of function for functional PCA in R - Functional Data Analysis

Tags: r, time-series, pca

I have discrete measurements of river flow spanning 22 years. As river flow is naturally continuous, I have attempted to fit a function to the data.

```
library(FDA) 
set.seed(1) 

### 3 years of flow data
base = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,5,5,4,4,4,3,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1)
year1 = sapply(base, function(x){x + runif(1)})
year2 = sapply(base, function(x){x + runif(1)})
year3 = sapply(base, function(x){x + runif(1)})

flow.mat = matrix(c(year1, year2, year3), ncol = 3)
```

Whilst Fourier basis systems are recommended for periodic data, the true data does not exhibit a strongly repeating pattern (ignore data simulation for this assumption). It also contains important extreme values. Therefore, I attempted to fit bSpline basis systems to the data.

```
sp.basis=create.bspline.basis(c(1,length(base)), norder=6, nbasis=15)
sb.fd=smooth.basis(1:length(base), flow.mat, sp.basis)$fd
```

Ultimately, I intend on using the flow data as a covariate in a regression model with a monthly interval. This poses an issue as I fit annual functions to the data, as this provided an improved fit for monthly data, given the data lack of temporal independence.

Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible for me to subset the generated functions, selecting a month at a time.

I suspect this is not possible, therefore, is it possible to run a fPCA on subsetted data, as I intend on using the fPCA scores as the covariate in the model?

So far I have been completely unsuccessful in running a subsetted fPCA. Instead, I have been obtaining annual scores via the following:

```
pca.flow=pca.fd(sb.fd, 2)
```

Comment: Just a comment: your data climbs from t=1 to 28, then goes down from t=28 to 35. If is really a 3 years observation, it does not follow an annual cycle. Therefore the explanatory factor is not the time but something else (weather, dam management,...). Maybe you find this external factor and base your forecast on this.

Comment: Sorry about the issue with t. I actually have daily measurements, I just provided a rushed simulation here as I am not allowed to release any of the data.

You are correct about the processes controlling flow being more complicated than just time. However, as flow will be used as a covariate to explain another variable (hydrological state), I have not put much focus into finding out what is driving flow. Instead, I am looking into how flow changes with hydrological state, but converting the flow data into a time-series function to get a more informative statistic than daily flow.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into much sophistication, I just plotted your data and made a polynomial fit. I did use a 4 degree polynomial because it is wave with 3 ups and downs (4 is one more than the extrema of the fitting curve). A a matter of facts, degree 5 or more did not gave a significant improvement.

What about doing the same for you 22 years time series?

[image]

Comment: I can get relatively good fits to the data. However, the issue I am having is subsetting the fit for input into fPCA. 

If, for example, each data point in the simulated flow data represents a weekly flow measure, I have fit a function, similar to the one you fit above, for 52 weeks of flow data (annual function). However, as I require monthly fPCA scores as a covariate, I need to subset this curve into 4 week/monthly segments for input into a fPCA. It is the subsetting that I am struggling with, unfortunately.